# Unlock screen for ec2-user

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, gnu-screen, password-recovery

I accidently locked **screen** under ec2-user (pressed C-a C-x). As far as I know ec2-user  has no password.

Now I'm prompted for password to unlock.

I do not want to terminate the process running under that screen. Is there any way to unlock the screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a different session, login as root and reset your user password.

```
sudo passwd ec2-user
```